# A program that prints characters based on the frequency of its use

Tags: arrays, c

I need to make a program that will print characters in a word on how frequent it is used. The unique characters will be printed in increasing order (spaces are ignored), if there are ties the character with lower ascii value will be printed first.

For an example if the input is hello world, the letters "h", "e", "w", "r" and "d" are only used once, the character "o" is used twice and the character "l" is used thrice. Since h,e,w,r,d are tie we should sort it into d,e,h,r,w. Then next would be o since it is used twice and then last is l. Thus if the input is hello world the output must be dehrwol. On my current program the problem is that when there are ties, it would not sort it alphabetically so the output is hewrdol instead of dehrwol.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int times[256];

int cmpLetters(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (times[*(char *)a] > times[*(char *)b]) - (times[*(char *)a] < times[*(char *)b]);
}

int main()
{
    char letters[256];
    int i, j, k, lnum, t;
    char s[1000];

    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);

    // Init occurrences as 0
    memset(times, 0, sizeof(times));

    for (i = lnum = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (times[s[i]]++ == 0)
            letters[lnum++] = s[i];

    // Sort letters by number of occurrences
    qsort(letters, lnum, sizeof(char), cmpLetters);

    char *new = malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 1));

    for (j = k = 0; j < lnum; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < times[letters[j]]; i++)
            new[k++] = letters[j];

    // new[k] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < lnum; i++)
    {
        if (letters[i] != '\n' && letters[i] != ' ')
            printf("%c", letters[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMO all those arrays makes the code unnecessary complex. I think an array of a struct like: `struct lc { char c; unsigned freq;}` would make things much much simpler.

Comment: Your comparison function doesn't look at both count and letter.  You will need a two-part comparison — which of the two entries has the larger count, and if the counts are the same, which of the two entries comes first.

Comment: Your code is hard to read because of all the blank lines and lack of indentation. I've reformatted it for you.

Comment: Having looked at your code, I don't think you record enough data to be able to do the sorting without losing the information about which letter has which frequency.  You almost certainly need a structure along the lines outlined by @SupportUkraine.

Comment: If you don't yet know about structures, say so.  They are the best way to go, but there are (painful) alternatives if you write your own sort / compare functions and use two arrays in parallel.  There may be other techniques I'm not remembering, but using a structure will make it easy and not using a structure makes it harder.  But, if you've not learned about structures yet, that makes structures 'unviable' for you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of you problems is that your `cmpLetters` only sorts based on the frequency count. It should also sort based on the characters in case the frequency is the same.

That said it seems that your code is unnecessary complex. Instead of all the arrays you should use an array of a struct that holds the character and the frequency.

A naive but simple implementation is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct lc 
{ 
    char c;
    unsigned freq;
};

int cmpLetters(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct lc* lca = (struct lc*)a;
    struct lc* lcb = (struct lc*)b;
    
    if (lca->freq > lcb->freq) return 1;
    if (lca->freq < lcb->freq) return -1;
    
    // Even frequecy so sort on the character
    if (lca->c > lcb->c) return 1;
    if (lca->c < lcb->c) return -1;
    return 0;
}

#define ARR_SZ (256)

int main(void)
{
    struct lc data[ARR_SZ];
    for (int i=0; i < ARR_SZ; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = (struct lc){' ', UINT_MAX};
    }
    
    char text[] = "hello world";
    
    for (int i=0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] != ' ')
        {
            if (data[(unsigned char)text[i]].freq == UINT_MAX)
            {
                data[(unsigned char)text[i]].freq = 0;
                data[(unsigned char)text[i]].c = text[i];
            }
            data[(unsigned char)text[i]].freq += 1;
        }
    }
    
    qsort(data, ARR_SZ, sizeof(struct lc), cmpLetters);
    
    for (int i=0; data[i].freq != UINT_MAX; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c", data[i].c);
    }
            
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
dehrwol
```